# MySQL server start fails

Tags: mysql, installation

I was trying to reset a forgotten password by accessing server as root, with --skip-grant-tables, as some tutorials suggested. However, I think I messed some internal configurations. I tried reinstalling already, running commands as sudo. I looked in the binlog.index folder and the file is indeed not there, however, this is currently where I am stuck, any help would be greatly appreciated.

typing 'Service mysql status', gives me:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server

   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)

   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-06-27 07:47:05 MST; 6s ago

     Docs: man:mysqld(8)

           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html

  Process: 4905 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

  Process: 4866 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql-8.0/mysql-systemd-start pre 

(code=exited, status=0/SUCC

 Main PID: 4905 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

   Status: "SERVER_BOOTING"

    Error: 13 (Permission denied)

Jun 27 07:47:05 adnan-UX330UAK systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
**Jun 27 07:47:05 adnan-UX330UAK mysqld[4905]: mysqld: File './binlog.index' not found (OS errno 13 - P**

Jun 27 07:47:05 adnan-UX330UAK mysqld[4905]: 2019-06-27T14:47:05.873368Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Serv

Jun 27 07:47:05 adnan-UX330UAK mysqld[4905]: 2019-06-27T14:47:05.874893Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Serve

Jun 27 07:47:05 adnan-UX330UAK mysqld[4905]: 2019-06-27T14:47:05.875020Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Serv

Jun 27 07:47:05 adnan-UX330UAK systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/

Jun 27 07:47:05 adnan-UX330UAK systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Jun 27 07:47:05 adnan-UX330UAK systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.

I tried looking for the './binlog.index file' and it's not in the folder.
```

typing 'service MySQL start, gives me':

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I looked in journalct1, and it says 'Line: 79 dlopen failed: libnm-glib.so.2:', I hope that helps. Journalct1 is below:

```
    Jun 27 08:03:42 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: testNetwork File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 745 Invoked Function: CNetEnvironment::testDnsAccess Return Code: -29294576 (0xFE41001
Jun 27 08:03:42 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: TestNetEnv File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 370 No DNS connectivity. Retesting connectivity to the secure gateway in 5 seconds.
Jun 27 08:03:47 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: CNWMgrHelper File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/linux/NWMgrHelper.cpp Line: 79 dlopen failed: libnm-glib.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No suc
Jun 27 08:03:47 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: createSingletonInstance File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/linux/NWMgrHelper.cpp Line: 151 Invoked Function: CNWMgrHelper::CNWMgrHelper Return Code: 
Jun 27 08:03:47 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: CNetInterface File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 188 Failed to load libnm library, features like TND may not work properl
Jun 27 08:03:47 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: EnumerateInterfaces File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 1400 Invoked Function: CNetInterface::getDnsConfiguration Return C
Jun 27 08:03:47 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: EnumerateInterfaces File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 1400 Invoked Function: CNetInterface::getDnsConfiguration Return C
Jun 27 08:03:47 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: CNWMgrHelper File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/linux/NWMgrHelper.cpp **Line: 79 dlopen failed: libnm-glib.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No suc**
Jun 27 08:03:47 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: createSingletonInstance File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/linux/NWMgrHelper.cpp Line: 151 Invoked Function: CNWMgrHelper::CNWMgrHelper Return Code: 
Jun 27 08:03:47 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: CNetInterface File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 188 Failed to load libnm library, features like TND may not work properl
Jun 27 08:03:47 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: EnumerateInterfaces File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 1400 Invoked Function: CNetInterface::getDnsConfiguration Return C
Jun 27 08:03:47 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: EnumerateInterfaces File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 1400 Invoked Function: CNetInterface::getDnsConfiguration Return C
Jun 27 08:03:47 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: testDnsAccess File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 903 Invoked Function: DNSRequest::Query Return Code: -29294576 (0xFE410010) Descript
Jun 27 08:03:47 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: testNetwork File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 745 Invoked Function: CNetEnvironment::testDnsAccess Return Code: -29294576 (0xFE41001
Jun 27 08:03:47 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: TestNetEnv File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 370 No DNS connectivity. Retesting connectivity to the secure gateway in 5 seconds.
Jun 27 08:03:52 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: CNWMgrHelper File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/linux/NWMgrHelper.cpp Line: 79 dlopen failed: libnm-glib.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No suc
Jun 27 08:03:52 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: createSingletonInstance File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/linux/NWMgrHelper.cpp Line: 151 Invoked Function: CNWMgrHelper::CNWMgrHelper Return Code: 
Jun 27 08:03:52 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: CNetInterface File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 188 Failed to load libnm library, features like TND may not work properl
Jun 27 08:03:52 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: EnumerateInterfaces File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 1400 Invoked Function: CNetInterface::getDnsConfiguration Return C
Jun 27 08:03:52 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: EnumerateInterfaces File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 1400 Invoked Function: CNetInterface::getDnsConfiguration Return C
Jun 27 08:03:52 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: CNWMgrHelper File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/linux/NWMgrHelper.cpp Line: 79 dlopen failed: libnm-glib.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No suc
Jun 27 08:03:52 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: createSingletonInstance File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/linux/NWMgrHelper.cpp Line: 151 Invoked Function: CNWMgrHelper::CNWMgrHelper Return Code: 
Jun 27 08:03:52 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: CNetInterface File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 188 Failed to load libnm library, features like TND may not work properl
Jun 27 08:03:52 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: EnumerateInterfaces File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 1400 Invoked Function: CNetInterface::getDnsConfiguration Return C
Jun 27 08:03:52 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: EnumerateInterfaces File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 1400 Invoked Function: CNetInterface::getDnsConfiguration Return C
Jun 27 08:03:52 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: testDnsAccess File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 903 Invoked Function: DNSRequest::Query Return Code: -29294576 (0xFE410010) Descript
Jun 27 08:03:52 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: testNetwork File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 745 Invoked Function: CNetEnvironment::testDnsAccess Return Code: -29294576 (0xFE41001
Jun 27 08:03:52 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: TestNetEnv File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 370 No DNS connectivity. Retesting connectivity to the secure gateway in 5 seconds.
Jun 27 08:03:57 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: CNWMgrHelper File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/linux/NWMgrHelper.cpp Line: 79 dlopen failed: libnm-glib.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No suc
Jun 27 08:03:57 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: createSingletonInstance File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/linux/NWMgrHelper.cpp Line: 151 Invoked Function: CNWMgrHelper::CNWMgrHelper Return Code: 
Jun 27 08:03:57 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: CNetInterface File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 188 Failed to load libnm library, features like TND may not work properl
Jun 27 08:03:57 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: EnumerateInterfaces File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 1400 Invoked Function: CNetInterface::getDnsConfiguration Return C
Jun 27 08:03:57 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: EnumerateInterfaces File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 1400 Invoked Function: CNetInterface::getDnsConfiguration Return C
Jun 27 08:03:57 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: CNWMgrHelper File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/linux/NWMgrHelper.cpp Line: 79 dlopen failed: libnm-glib.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No suc
Jun 27 08:03:57 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: createSingletonInstance File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/linux/NWMgrHelper.cpp Line: 151 Invoked Function: CNWMgrHelper::CNWMgrHelper Return Code: 
Jun 27 08:03:57 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: CNetInterface File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 188 Failed to load libnm library, features like TND may not work properl
Jun 27 08:03:57 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: EnumerateInterfaces File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 1400 Invoked Function: CNetInterface::getDnsConfiguration Return C
Jun 27 08:03:57 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: EnumerateInterfaces File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 1400 Invoked Function: CNetInterface::getDnsConfiguration Return C
Jun 27 08:03:57 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: testDnsAccess File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 903 Invoked Function: DNSRequest::Query Return Code: -29294576 (0xFE410010) Descript
Jun 27 08:03:57 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: testNetwork File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 745 Invoked Function: CNetEnvironment::testDnsAccess Return Code: -29294576 (0xFE41001
Jun 27 08:03:57 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: TestNetEnv File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 370 No DNS connectivity. Retesting connectivity to the secure gateway in 5 seconds.
Jun 27 08:04:02 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: CNWMgrHelper File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/linux/NWMgrHelper.cpp Line: 79 dlopen failed: libnm-glib.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No suc
Jun 27 08:04:02 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: createSingletonInstance File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/linux/NWMgrHelper.cpp Line: 151 Invoked Function: CNWMgrHelper::CNWMgrHelper Return Code: 
Jun 27 08:04:02 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: CNetInterface File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 188 Failed to load libnm library, features like TND may not work properl
Jun 27 08:04:02 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: EnumerateInterfaces File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 1400 Invoked Function: CNetInterface::getDnsConfiguration Return C
Jun 27 08:04:02 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: EnumerateInterfaces File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 1400 Invoked Function: CNetInterface::getDnsConfiguration Return C
Jun 27 08:04:02 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: CNWMgrHelper File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/linux/NWMgrHelper.cpp Line: 79 dlopen failed: libnm-glib.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No suc
Jun 27 08:04:02 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: createSingletonInstance File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/linux/NWMgrHelper.cpp Line: 151 Invoked Function: CNWMgrHelper::CNWMgrHelper Return Code: 
Jun 27 08:04:02 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: CNetInterface File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 188 Failed to load libnm library, features like TND may not work properl
Jun 27 08:04:02 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: EnumerateInterfaces File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 1400 Invoked Function: CNetInterface::getDnsConfiguration Return C
Jun 27 08:04:02 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: EnumerateInterfaces File: ../../vpn/Common/Utility/NetInterface_unix.cpp Line: 1400 Invoked Function: CNetInterface::getDnsConfiguration Return C
Jun 27 08:04:02 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: testDnsAccess File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 903 Invoked Function: DNSRequest::Query Return Code: -29294576 (0xFE410010) Descript
Jun 27 08:04:02 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: testNetwork File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 745 Invoked Function: CNetEnvironment::testDnsAccess Return Code: -29294576 (0xFE41001
Jun 27 08:04:02 adnan-UX330UAK acvpnagent[1612]: Function: TestNetEnv File: ../../vpn/Agent/NetEnvironment.cpp Line: 370 No DNS connectivity. Retesting connectivity to the secure gateway in 5 seconds.
```

Comment: "However, I think I messed some internal configurations. I tried reinstalling already"...… reinstalling is only done by first REMOVing everything. Currently you have a corrupt installation (which therefore will not start). Go back to your backup, or delete everything and re-install from scratch.

Comment: I used the procedure outlined here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-linux-uninstalling.html. However, I glanced over the end where it mentions, that the workbench and other setting are not removed.

Comment: Typing this command: sudo chown -R mysql: /var/lib/mysql, got the server to start, but I still have issues, when I try to start as root to reset my password. How would I do a complete uninstall?

Comment: Getting the server to start is good. Show the details of what you have troubles with. Your removing URL is for workbench rather than the server. You're acvpnagent issue is totally unrelated to MySQL. Jumping from a 1/2 working solution to just uninstall isn't going to help you. Describe your current issue (edit the question if needed).